# Is it possible to show data by row rather than per column?

Tags: mysql

My sample table: `SELECT * FROM sample`

```
+-----+-------+---------+
| id  | fname |  lname  |
+-----+-------+---------+
|     |       |         |
|  1  |   Me  | subject |
|  2  |   I   | subject |
|  3  | Myself| subject |
+-----+-------+---------+
```

Is it possible to have this output using distinct on lname or any formula?

```
+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| id  | lname |  fname  |  fname  |  fname  |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|     |       |         |         |         |
|  1  |subject|    me   |    I    | Myself  |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Thanks.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you want but maybe enough

```
select min(id) as id, 
       lname, 
       group_concat(fname separator ' ' order by id) as fname
from your_table
group by lname
```

Comment: group_concat() will create single column not multiple column as per question

Comment: Yes, that is why I said *Not exactly what OP wants* in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The number of columns and the expressions to return those columns has to be specified in the statement. In the example you give, yes, it's possible to write a statement that returns the specified resultset.

For example:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.lname
     , ( SELECT f1.fname
           FROM mytable f1
          WHERE f1.lname = t.lname
          ORDER BY f1.id
          LIMIT 0,1
       ) AS fname
     , ( SELECT f2.fname
           FROM mytable f2
          WHERE f2.lname = t.lname
          ORDER BY f2.id
          LIMIT 1,1
       ) AS fname
     , ( SELECT f3.fname
           FROM mytable f3
          WHERE f3.lname = t.lname
          ORDER BY f3.id
          LIMIT 2,1
       ) AS fname
  FROM ( SELECT MIN(m.id) AS id
              , m.lname
           FROM mytable m
          GROUP BY m.lname
       ) t
```

In the more general case, it's not possible to vary the number of columns returned by a single `SELECT` statement. The example above could be extended to return four, or five, or more values of `fname`. But it's a finite number of columns.